# How do I use dynamically sized data structures that are persistent in memory

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory, std

I'm working on building a range minimum query program in C++ but I'm having a hard time working with dynamically sized vectors that are used throughout the program. Right now I am using a `size_t**` to make a 2d array of indexes to an array of elements, but it's not very nice to work with. I would much rather leverage existing c++ data structures like vectors, but I'm not sure how to make a member variable that is a pointer to a vector or some other data structure that can be manipulated in this way and access from anywhere in the class.

When I tried using a `vector` I could populate it and manipulate it in `PrecomputedRMQ()`, but when I tried to query in `rmq()` the memory was inaccessible and I would segfault.

In essence, how do I replace this use of `size_t**` with a `vector<vector<size_t>>`, and more generally, how do I initialize and allocate pointers to member variables of builtin data structures?

In Header:

```
private:
size_t** table;
```

In my cpp: Here is how I'm constructing my table right now

```
PrecomputedRMQ::PrecomputedRMQ(const RMQEntry* elems, size_t numElems) {
  numElems = numElems;
  table = new size_t*[numElems];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < numElems; i++) {
    table[i] = new size_t[numElems];
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < numElems; i++) {
    table[i][i] = i;
  }
  // then I go on to populate the table using DP
}

size_t PrecomputedRMQ::rmq(size_t low, size_t high) const {
  return table[low][high];
}
```

Comment: If you use `std::vector`, you would not need to dynamically allocate anything anymore (it will do it for you) :)

Comment: What does DP mean in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to replacing your current explicit memory handling with `std::vector`, you don't need the allocation loop.

All you need is e.g.

```
table = std::vector<std::vector<size_t>>(numElems, std::vector<size_t>(numElems));
```

That will create a vector of vectors, with all sizes already set and all elements allocated and zero-initialized (which differs from your current code which leaves the majority of elements uninitialized!).

After this your initialization loop and the use in `rmq` should work as is. Iff the indexes `low` and `high` are in range of course.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

(only slightly tested)

```
#include <memory>

template<typename DataType>
class Board {
  std::unique_ptr<DataType[]> board;
public:
  const int rows = 8;
  const int cols = 8;

  Board(int row, int col, const DataType& filler = {}) :
    rows(row),
    cols(col),
    board(std::make_unique<DataType[]>(row*col)) {
      std::fill_n(board.get(), rows*cols, filler);
    }

  DataType *operator[](int row) { return board.get()+row*cols; }
  const DataType *operator[](int row) const { return board.get()+row*cols; }
};

template<typename DataType, int crows = 8, int ccols = 8>
class FixBoard {
  std::array<DataType, crows*ccols> board;

public:
  const int rows = crows;
  const int cols = ccols;

  FixBoard(const DataType& filler = {}) {
    board.fill(filler);
  }

  DataType *operator[](int row) { return board.data()+row*cols; }
  const DataType *operator[](int row) const { return board.data()+row*cols; }
};
```

Board can be sized on creation from some input, FixBoard requires compile time knowledge of the size.

Usage example

```
#include <iostream>
constexpr char BlockChar { '\xB2' }; // 178
constexpr char EmptyChar { '.' };
constexpr char BlankChar { ' ' };

template <typename BoardType>
void Display(const BoardType& board) {
  for (int i = 0; i < board.rows; ++i ) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board.cols; ++j ) {
      //std::cout << this->operator[](i)[j];
      std::cout << board[i][j];
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}

void Test() {
  constexpr int sx = 6, sy = 10;
  Board<char> board(sx, sy, BlankChar);
  board[3][5] = BlockChar;
  Display(board);

  FixBoard<char, sx, sy> fixBoard(BlockChar);
  fixBoard[3][5] = BlankChar;
  Display(fixBoard);
}
```

Missing headers, more constexpr, const and test.